# getActions(accountName), possible names? | actions.action_trace.act.name

Tags: javascript

Using eosjs, I query all outgoing transactions using

```
const actions = (await eos.getActions(accountName)).actions;
```

map it, and console.log() the sorted and filtered result.

The problem is, depending on `actions.action_trace.act.name`, the file structure alters. So far I found following names `buyram, buyrambytes, delegatebw, newaccount`

Where can I find all the names?

I haven't found an answer in the docs nor google.
`actions.action_trace.act.data` could contain the following:

```
from, memo, quantity, to, payer, quant, receiver, bytes, stake_cpu_quantity, stake_net_quantity, transfer
```

I push the finished example this Sunday evening to this Github repo: https://github.com/MarcelBlockchain/react-eos-wallet

Comment: are you asking about names of actions of a particular contract? you can fetch the abi

Comment: every contract has it's own names and file structure? I just need the standard output data to show it in a wallet

Answer (score 1):

```
node_modules/eosjs/lib/schema/eosio_system.json
```

helped me. In case it's not one of the most used ones, I just return the whole object